# Can't reply to post

Tags: discussion

I posted a question and many people have answered it, however I cannot reply. Am I doing something wrong?

There isn't anything like a reply button/link.

Link for my post:
[How to Replace a string by another in a text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451057/how-to-replace-a-string-by-another-in-a-text-file)

Comment: You don't reply: it is a wiki, not a forum. Edit your question with the additional information people are asking for.

Comment: You should be able to comment on answers to your own question, with the same user account you asked the question with. But it seems you have two accounts now, and not enough rep to comment on the other account's question. You may want to see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 3):

That's because, [as I pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451057/how-to-replace-a-string-by-another-in-a-text-file#comment819031_451057), you asked your first question with an unregistered account. [Register that account](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts), at which point you will be able to edit and comment on your question ([among other privileges](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/why-register)).

Answer (score 0):

You can add your reply in the form of comment. There is no 'reply' button

Comment: The OP cannot comment since they don't have enough reputation, and they are (were) logged in as a different user to the one that asked the original question.

Comment: Oh that's true...